# Word for "A symbol that means a word/phrase"

Tags: single-word-requests, symbols

[This article](http://www.theverge.com/2013/7/5/4495178/paul-mathis-the-symbol-th-android-keyboard-range) about using Ћ to stand for *the* made me think about how different symbols represent words or phrases. For example: @ means *at*; % means *per cent*; # can mean *pound* or *number*; ♥ can mean *love*, as in "I ♥ NY".

It seems right to call these *abbreviations*, but:

- Abbreviations can include non-symbols, like AZ for *Arizona*
- The symbol may have characters not found in the word (like $ has an *S* shape in it, even though *s* is not in *dollar*), contrary to some definitions of *abbreviation*

One word I found was [*ligature*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature), which seems to describe & and the proposed Ћ well. But:

- *Ligature* does not describe some symbols shown above (like #)
- *Ligature* describes symbols that do not mean words (like æ)

The symbols listed above are what one might see in informal (but standard) shorthand, and it's these I want to describe. Mathematical symbols (like using = to mean *equal* or *the same*) can be in the same category. Alphabetic symbols, like X or O to mean *kisses* or *hugs*, may be included too.

Is there a name for (and only for) symbols like these?

Comment: "It does not describe some symbols shown above (like #); It describes symbols that do not mean words (like æ)" --> it's not it.

Comment: I have heard that the dollar symbol is a U and S printed on the same space, but that's probably folklore.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**[Logogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logogram)**

> A logogram, or logograph, is a grapheme which represents a word or a morpheme (the smallest meaningful unit of language). This stands in contrast to phonograms, which represent phonemes (speech sounds) or combinations of phonemes, and determinatives, which mark semantic categories.
>
> Logograms are commonly known also as "**ideograms**". Strictly speaking, however, ideograms represent ideas directly rather than words and morphemes...

Other dictionaries seem to equate ideograms with logograms. [Dictionay.com World English Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/ideogram) for example:

**Ideogram**:

> 1. a sign or symbol, used in such writing systems as those of China or Japan, that directly represents a concept, idea, or thing rather than
>      a word or set of words for it
> 2. any graphic sign or symbol, such as %, @, &, etc.

Comment: Nice answer!  This works for a subset of the signs the OP asked for, but not for the Ћ at least.

Comment: Everything I read about *ideogram* seems to fit perfectly with what I'm trying to say! Thanks!